# Redux-tookit "mutate" the object by overwrting a field vs return an immutably-updated value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutability, redux-toolkit

I'm new to react and redux-toolkit. When I went through the redux-toolkit usage guide(https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide) I found out that I could either "mutate" the object or return an immutably-updated value. However, I got confused when they actually behave differently.

This is my todoSlice

```
const todoSlice = createSlice({
name: 'todo',
initialState:{
    todoArray: [],
},
reducers: {
    addTodo(state, action) {
        state.todoArray.push({ id: new Date().toISOString(), content: action.payload });
    },
    removeTodoMutate(state, action) {
        state.todoArray =  state.todoArray.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
    },
    removeTodoWithImmutably(state, action) {//NOT WORKING
        return state.todoArray.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
    }
},});
```

This is my TodoList

```
const TodoList = () => {
const listOfTodos = useSelector(state => state.todo.todoArray);
return (
<div>
    { listOfTodos && listOfTodos.length > 0 && (listOfTodos.map((todo) => (
         <TodoItem key={todo.id} id={todo.id} todoContent={todo.content} />
    )))}
    {!listOfTodos || listOfTodos.length === 0  && (<h1>No Items</h1>)}
</div>
);};
```

This is my TodoItem

```
const TodoItem = (props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const deleteClickHandler = () => {
    dispatch(removeTodoWithImmutably(props.id));
}
return (
<div>
    <h2>
        {props.todoContent} 
        <button onClick={deleteClickHandler}>DELETE</button>
    </h2>
</div>);};
```

The problems were two removeTodo reducers in the todoSlice, the removeTodoMutate would work normaly, the removeTodoWithImmutably would clear out the entire TodoList once I trigger the action. When I checked the redux devtool the correct action was triggered, and the state was changed correctly.

Could anyone please explain to me why this would happened? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `removeTodoWithImmutably` is changing the state shape itself.

Before, your state has the shape `{ todoArray: [ ... ] }`, but then you return a new state of the shape `[ ... ]`.

So, instead of

```
    return state.todoArray.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
```

do

```
    return { todoArray: state.todoArray.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload) };
```

Generally, give https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers a read.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes sense now. But why does the state in the redux-devtool still show the correct state?

Comment: I don't really think it does, they probably just look very similar?